# How to reference Free/Busy menu in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

You know that short Busy/Free menu when you schedule something in Google Calendar? The one denoted by, what I assume to be, a suitcase.

How do I refer to that in a script? Similar to `setLocation()` or `setColor()`, I thought - but `setFreeBusy()`, or something like that, doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: There is no scripted access to the Calendar UI.  Except that which is described in card service.

Comment: Looks like there was a feature request for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/36764243) - maybe create a new one as this one seems to be dead?

Comment: @Cooper what are you talking about?